# jqgrid sort: i have to make sort by date in the jqgrid column

Tags: jqgrid

I have a column name: `Date`

I have a jqgrid code as:

```
{
name:'a.INC_DATE', 
index:'a.INC_DATE',
width: 100,
searchoptions: {
    sopt: ['eq', 'ne','cn']
}
```

i get the values of column date ,from this data base index.

I have already placed the sort order in my code:

```
pager: '#pager',
rowNum: 500,
rowList:[500,100,20],
sortname: 'a.INC_DATE',
sortorder: 'desc',
viewrecords: true,
sortable: true,
height: 400,
width: 800, 
shrinkToFit: false,
```

by i dose not get the sort function.

so on click the column heading  in the table,i need to get the sort values.

i am waiting for your nice answer kindly..,

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend you to use special characters like dot in the `name` property of jqGrid. Moreover you should avoid to use special characters in `index` too. In general you can use `index:'a.INC_DATE'` but only in case of *remote* `datatype` values: `"json"` or `"xml"`. By the way you can't use different values for `index` and `name` in case of usage `loadonce: true` property of jqGrid.

Moreover it's important to understand that it you use `datatype: "json"` or `datatype: "xml"` *without* `loadonce: true` you are free in the choice of `index` properties of description of columns in `colModel`. jqGrid just send the value of the `index` property to the server as the value of `sidx` parameter, but in the case *the server code* is responsible for sorting of jqGrid. So if the sorting is work incorrectly that you have examine your server code for the problem.